# How to append multiple unique elements to the same set of columns in Python?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, append

I am trying to take a unique identifier/key from one column in a data frame and appending it to another data frame to the SAME set of elements in both columns. Both data frames are as follows:

```
         df1                              df2
Geogkey    Brand  Week               date       Impressions
TMZ43434   x      6/16/18           6/14/18       798798
KRO36783   y      6/16/18           6/21/18       562314
....                                6/28/18       462534
n
```

There are several more dates in df2 leading up to August, but I have not included them for the sake of brevity. I want to take EACH unique Geogkey from df1 and append them to df2, so each row of the specific date and impressions match with a geogkey. 
The set of dates and impressions in df2 will continuously repeat down the dataframe with each combination corresponding to a unique geogkey - which will also duplicate each time. So the final data frame to look like this:

```
Geogkey    date    Impressions
TMZ43434  6/14/18   798798
TMZ43434  6/21/18   562314
TMZ43434  6/28/18   462534
KRO36783  6/14/18   798798
KRO36783  6/21/18   562314
KRO36783  6/28/18   462534
```

This will continuously repeat for each geogkey. The code I have so far is:

```
empty <- data.frame(df2$date, df2$impressions)

#creates a new data frame with unique geogkeys
geogname <- unique(data.frame(df1$GEOGKEY))

#create some function that will index each unique geogkey and make a new 
column for df2 with that name (e.g. df2$geogkey <- some function)

new_df <- rbind(empty, df2)
#this should theoretically append all the geogkeys to the dates and 
impressions
```

Do I need to write some for loop for this? I'm stuck and not sure how to proceed. I'm trying to do this in Pandas as well.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

correct me if I am wrong but it looks like you are trying to repeat every key with every combination of "date" and "impression". Something like this would work.

```
df <- data.frame()
for(i in unique(df1$GEOKEY){
  for(j in 1:nrow(df2)){

       df <- rbind(df, 
                   data.frame('key' = i, 'date' = df2[j,1], 'impressions' =  df2[j,2]))

   }
}
```

With a big data frame this is a bit of a cumbersome solution. Also I have assumed the rows in `df2` are unique.

Comment: Whoops, I explained the output wrong and edited it above. Not EVERY combination but repeat every key just for each unique row or combination of date & impressions. I added an extra row as well for clarity

Comment: I thought that might be the case. All you have to do is remove the `k` loop entirely and replace the k iterator with `j`.

Comment: If you could mark the question as accepted that would be appreciated and it would close the post.

Comment: @manutd93: are you familiar with the question acceptance process here? While it is not mandatory, it is a nice way of thanking people who have assisted you.